# Pass Spark Config Parameters in Azure Databricks Jar Job

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to run a Scala Spring Boot Application onto an Azure Databricks spark cluster.
I am using the Jar upload to execute the application.

The application needs the "spring.profiles.active" details which I can normally pass while using a spark-submit command

e.g. spark-submit --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dspring.profiles.active=test' --conf spark.executer.extraJavaOptions='-Dspring.profiles.active=test'

But in the databricks jar upload workflows like the below case, how can pass these spark configs?

[image: Azure Databricks Task]

Answer (score 0):

Add the configuration in scala program as below.

```
val  sparkConf  =  new  SparkConf.set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dspring.profiles.active=test").set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Dspring.profiles.active=test")
val  spark  =  SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).appName("yourAppName").getOrCreate()
```

Create a jar file and run databricks job.

Below is the sample code, i used to create job in databricks.

```
package example

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object  Print {
    def  main(args: Array[String]):  Unit  = {
    val  sparkConf  =  new SparkConf().set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dspring.profiles.active=test").set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Dspring.profiles.active=test")
    val  sprk  =  SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).appName("yourAppName").getOrCreate()
    println(sparkConf.get("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions"))
    println(sparkConf.get("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions"))
    println("Hello world")
    }
    }
```

I created Jar and added to databricks job.

[image]

After running the job this the output in logs.

```
2023-05-05T11:46:46.252+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1510342K->140114K(1816576K)] 2105227K->735007K(6090240K), 0.0811533 secs] [Times: user=0.26 sys=0.00, real=0.08 secs] 
Executing command, time = 1683287205433.
-Dspring.profiles.active=test
-Dspring.profiles.active=test
Hello world
```

Try running this for your scala code.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Databricks Jar upload workflow to execute a Scala Spring Boot application on an Azure Databricks cluster, you can pass Spark configurations by leveraging the spark.conf property. Here's how you can specify the spring.profiles.active property:

Package your Scala Spring Boot application into a Jar file.

Upload the Jar file to Azure Databricks using the Databricks UI or API.

In your Databricks notebook or job, create a cell with the following code:

scala
dbutils.fs.put("/databricks/init//00-setup-spark-conf.sh", """
|#!/bin/bash
|
|echo "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Dspring.profiles.active=test" >> /databricks/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
|echo "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -Dspring.profiles.active=test" >> /databricks/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
""".stripMargin, true)

// Replace  with a unique name for your job
Run the cell to create a shell script that sets the required Spark configurations. This script will be executed before your job starts.

In the same notebook or job, create another cell to run your Scala Spring Boot application:

%scala

// Your Scala Spring Boot application code here
When the job is executed, the shell script created in step 4 will set the spark.driver.extraJavaOptions and spark.executor.extraJavaOptions configurations in spark-defaults.conf. This will pass the spring.profiles.active property with the value "test" to your application.

Please note that this method sets the Spark configurations for the entire cluster. If you want to set the configurations for a specific job only, you can create a separate cluster for that job and set the configurations using the spark.conf.set(...) method in your Scala code before running the application.

Alternatively, if you are using Databricks CLI, you can achieve the same result by running the following command before executing your job:

databricks configure --token
databricks clusters spark.conf.set spark.driver.extraJavaOptions "-Dspring.profiles.active=test"
databricks clusters spark.conf.set spark.executor.extraJavaOptions "-Dspring.profiles.active=test"
This will configure the Spark cluster with the necessary options before running your Scala Spring Boot application.